# Telegram BotFather API

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to "communicate" with Telegram BotFather via API to create and configure new bots without actually "chat" with it?

It could be useful to create a bot programmatically.

Comment: No way, you need to send text

Comment: this is exactly i am looking for still. is it really suppose to be manual?

Comment: @Danish so far I couldn't find an automatic procedure to create a bot, so I suppose the manual creations is by design.

Comment: same here, i am going to do manual as well!

Comment: Looks like it's a protection from creation bots by other ones.